# Turn a string into a list before appending

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 lists I created and I want to append them from the sql query output. I thought of created them as string as `lst` and append the output but I get the error below.

```
list_A1 = []
list_A2 = []
list_A3 = []


for i, name  in enumerate(dataset['name'][1]['price']):
   .
   .
   .

   id_list = pd.read_sql_query(q, con=db)[price].tolist()
   lst = f"{lst_name}_{id}"

   #lst created the 3 list above.        

   lst.append(id_list).astype(int)

Error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Edit:

What I mean is on each loop `lst` = list_A1..
and each of those lists gets populated with the data from the sql query

Comment: `lst.append(id_list).astype(int)` will cause a problem too

Comment: you can't create variable using `f"{lst_name}_{id}"` - you may only use it as key in dictionary `all_lists[f"{lst_name}_{id}"] = []`

Comment: `lst` is a string object. You cannot perform an append on it.. You can concatenate your `lst` with a `+` to `str(id_list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't create variable using string `f"{lst_name}_{id}"`. You may only use it as key in dictionary `all_lists[f"{lst_name}_{id}"] = []`. And you should use dictionary

```
all_lists = {
   "list_A1": [],
   "list_A2": [],
   "list_A3": [],
}

for ... in ...:

   id_list = ....astype(int).tolist()
 
   key = f"{lst_name}_{id}"

   lst = all_lists[key]
   
   lst.append( id_list )
```

You could do it even dinamically

```
all_lists = {}  # empty dictionary

for ... in ...:

   id_list = ....astype(int).tolist()

   key = f"{lst_name}_{id}"

   # create list if not exists yet
   if key not in all_lists:
       all_lists[key] = []

   lst = all_lists[key]
   
   lst.append( id_list )
```

---

**BTW:** You can create variable with `vars()` or similar functions but it is not preferred. You have dictionary for this.

Comment: how do I call the list outside the loop?

Comment: `all_lists[key]` ie `all_lists["list_A1"]`. Because all lists are in dictionary so you can use them in `for`-loop and make code shorter. `for lst in all_lists.values(): ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can try follows,

```
list_A1 = []
list_A2 = []
list_A3 = []
for id_ in range(1,4,1):
    lst = f"list_A1"
    vars()[lst].append(id_)
print(list_A1)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Reference

1. [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Just curious: `range(1,4,1)` why this last `1` isn't 1 default?

Comment: Oh sorry, It was a mistake. Thanks